# Message Passing receiving end

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Work algorithm of extension**

For example, I am on site C, I see pageAction, click on it, script parsing needed information, then opens site A, script add all that information in textarea.

```
backround.js ---> c.js (signal to start parsing)
c.js ----> backround.js (message with information)
backround.js ----> a.js (that message, add in textarea) [Here I have problem]
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "test",
  "icons": { "16": "16.png",
             "48": "48.png",
             "128": "128.png" 
            },
 "page_action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "icon19.png",
    "default_title" : "TEST"
  },

  "background": {  
  "page": "html/background.html"
   },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://A_SITE"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/a.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://C_SITE"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/c.js"]
    },
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version":"31.0",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://C_SITE/*", "http://A_SITE/*"]
}
```

**c.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.c_go == "go"){
    //parsing here
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ some obj }); // HERE I SEND MESSAGE TO BACKGROUND
    }
 });
});
```

**a.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request){
      console.log(request); // NOTHING IN CONSOLE
    }
 });
});
```

**background.js**

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(changeInfo.status === "loading") {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('C_SITE') > -1) {
     chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
  }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

if (tab.url.indexOf('C_SITE') > -1){
    // HERE I SEND MESSAGE TO c.js TO PARSING
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {c_go: "go"});
  });
  // OPENS SITE_A
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "SITE_A", "active":true}, function(tab){
    // REQUEST FROM c.js
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      // SEND REQUEST TO TAB WITH SITE_A
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab) {
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, request);
      });
    });
  });
}
});
```

So, in console on SITE_A I see nothing in console. Its very strange, because I use the same code in **c.js** `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `chrome.tabs.query()` all the time ??? You did that in another question of yours, I corrected it in my answer, now you do it again !? What's the point  :( (The same goes for `$(document).ready()` - I explained why you don't need it, now you use it again...)

Comment: @ExpertSystem you wrote about context-menus. Its not good way in my situation, if you know, how to fix that bug, please post code

Comment: I wrote about one possible way to pass data from web-page to background-page. The code in the background-page is independent from the method used to pass data to it (and I explicitely noted that you can easily modify the data-passing mechanism to support e.g. page-actions). My comments above hold as much when using context-menus as when using page-actions and you might find it helpful to follow my suggestions. In any case, if my answer to your previous question was not good enough, you should not post a new (almost identical question), but update or comment on the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.onMessage` is an event listener so it needs to be defined before said event occurs in order to listen for it. Right now you have it sending a message `background -> c.js` then send a new message `c.js -> background.js`. This turns it into a `race condition` as your background page opens up the new tab and creates the event handler at the same time that `c.js` is trying to send a message. Instead, try to make it all one flow.

**c.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
  if(request.c_go == "go"){
    //parsing here
    sendResponse({ some obj }); // HERE I SEND MESSAGE TO BACKGROUND
  }
});
```

This changes the message `c -> background` to a response to the first message.

**background.js**

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{c_go:"go"},function(response){
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "SITE_A", "active":true}, function(newTab){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(newTab.id, {file:"a.js"},function(){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, response);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This makes is so that `Site A` isn't opened until you get the info from `Site C`.

Comment: Well put ! That's what I've been trying to tell him :)

Comment: @BeardFist I changed my code, in background I can see response in console, but nothing in console of a.js. (you have a bug - `newTab.id, request` need `response`).

Comment: @tim Thanks, I make some typos when typing off the cuff. As for a.js, it might be another race condition between injecting the script and sending the message. Doing it this way, you will want to not inject the script via your manifest, otherwise it might inject it twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens on page-action click:

1. You send message to C_SITE.
2. You create new tab with A_SITE.
3. You register an `onMessage` listener to receive messages from C_SITE.
4. You forward any messages from C_SITE to A_SITE.

Unfortunately, somewhere between 1 and 3 (before the listener is registered), C_SITE sends its message (which goes unnoticed).
You should always make sure your events are fired **after** the corresponding listeners are properly set-up.

---

<sub>See my comment above:

* You use `chrome.tabs.query()` unnecessarily and risk breaking your extension's behaviour (e.g. if another widnow happens to become unexpectedly active).

* You unnecessarily use `$(document).ready()`.</sub>